# Change output voltage of a charger using the shunt resistor?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, shunt

I have bought a 58v charger from asia and I selected the SLA one by mistake instead of Li-ion. It came with a 59.3v output when i want it to be more in the 58.3 range. My battery doesnt detect the 59.3 volts, I think it's to high, the BMS detects over-voltage.

1/ Is an SLA charger unuseable with 18650 14s8p battery, because a li-ion charger has an adaptive output ranging from 52-58?

2/ Can i change the 80N70 FET shunt's controlling resistor (it's 750 kiloOhm) on the circuit board to make the charger put out 58.5v instead of 59.3? 
[image]
[image]

Resistor r29 goes to 2 of the 80NF70 FET pins, the middle FET pin also is the ground output of the battery. Can i change the resistor from 750k? Can i use a pot? How do i know the value to get 58.3V?

Comment: You may be able to adjust the output voltage, but not by randomly changing components whose function is unknown. Trace the entire circuit on the secondary side of the transformer (including part numbers, values and designations - draw a professional looking schematic!) and understand how it works, then the solution should be obvious. If you still can't figure it out then post the 'reverse engineered' schematic here.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I added another pic. The R29 measures at 770k instead of 750k on the multimeter, it's beige color suggests it's not a precise, so perhaps that's why i am getting too high Voltage. Theoretically, I can check the two resistors that are attached to the 80NF70 and multiply them by the algebra given on the 80NF70 specifications to find which resistors achieve which output voltage. Hopefully, of all the parts, i could change only two resistors and perhaps use a pot and a resistor on one of them. SORRY! I dont understand circuit diagrams!!! i'm a biologist :)

Comment: Are you **sure** that your BMS will protect the Li-Ion battery from any "SLA-type" behaviour of the SLA charger e.g. incorrect (and less precise) termination voltage, continuous "float charge" etc., which are problems for Li-Ion batteries? Personally I wouldn't try to do what you are attempting, unless I was *very* sure that the *only* difference between the two chargers, was the output voltage (which you are trying to change). And I *doubt* that is the only difference. Sorry if that's not what you want to hear, but I don't want you to be injured if the battery goes "bang" :-(

Comment: The BMS specifies: Charge voltage 58.8V constant charge, constant current... so, if i can get it down from 59.3 it should be OK. I swapped the 770 resistor for a 730 one, and the voltage didn't change. I don't want to send it back to china for 20 dollars... Can I make a buck  converter for one volt on 59v, 3A?

Comment: Hi - I didn't get a notification of your comment, as there was no "@" mention of my name. :-( *"Can I make a buck converter for one volt on 59v, 3A?"* Now I've seen your update here (by chance), I notice that you've just asked that same question (perhaps because I didn't reply here, as I didn't get notified of your question!) at this link: "[Buck Converter for 59V to 58V?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/317548/)". People are already replying there, so no point in me duplicating replies here too. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty way to drop the supply by 1 V is to put two high-current diodes in series with the supply + line.  Each diode will drop the voltage 0.65 V for a total of 1.3 V which will take the supply down to 58 V.  Make sure each diode has the current rating for whatever current you expect to draw from the supply.  And you need to provide adequate heatsinking for the diodes as they will generate 1.3 x 8 = 10.4 W of heat if you are drawing 8 A.

This said, it is a BAD idea to use an SLA charger to charge Li-ion, because of the unreliability of the charger.  You can put more diodes in series to get the voltage down to let's say 56 V and do away with the 4.2 V constant-voltage charging that Li-ion chargers provide to maximize storage, but still a cheap SLA charger can malfunction and feed let's say 65 V through the diodes and burst the cells.

It does not appear that the FET is controlling the output voltage because it does not have a hefty heatsink.  Most likely it is just an active breaker that protects the supply from shorts or excessive output current.  If this is a DC to DC step-down converter, you would need to adjust the primary side circuit to adjust the output voltage.

I think your best bet is to purchase a Li-ion charger, and also you must use a balance-protection board, if you don't have one already.  If you can't find a 14S board, you can adapt a 17S or 20S board, I believe.