# Buck Converter for 59V to 58V?

Tags: resistors, dc-dc-converter, charger

Some batteries last twice as long if they are kept to 80 percent of their maximum charge. It's good to add a small adjustment to undervolt a charger output by 0.5 - 1V. Myself i have a CC/CV charger that is .5 volts too high for a given BMS.

How can I take the voltage down by .5 - 1V at the output?

Comment: A zener diode would get you a voltage drop different than 0.7V if you want.

Comment: That is true but I usually do not trust series-connected Zener diodes unless there is a permanent bias current. In this particular case, you won't drop \$V_Z\$ when the current is 0 (battery is charged) and you will probably need a small bleeder after the Zener to force it operating in its knee. No big deal but it might absorb a bit of power.

Comment: Maybe you can recalibrate your charger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvMlsP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. \$ V_{OUT} = V_{IN} - 0.7 \$*.

A silicon diode will drop about 0.7 V when more than a few milliamps is running through it.

Comment: @JackB: Thanks for correcting *silicone* to *silicon*. I have to reseal the shower today and my mind must have been thinking of the white gooey stuff ...

Answer (score 2):

At your very small input /output differential you will find it hard to get a chip to do this .You want to drop 1 Volt out of 59 .Even the most efficient buck converters would waste more power than a simple linear solution.When you have a big drop in percentage terms there is more to gain from the buck .Say if you want 12V from 24 then the linear will be at best 50% efficient and you would be winning with if the Chinese Alibaaber buck is 78% efficient .In your case a linear solution which could be diode     based as Transistor suggested will be cheaper and waste less power .

Comment: While everything you say is true, upvote wise, I've noticed it's better to not refer to other answers. Instead just put the solution in your own answer making your answer a more complete solution/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put a power diode in forward series with the positive supply.  Each diode will drop the voltage roughly 0.65 V.  A diode forward voltage increases only logarithmic with the current.  Make sure that the diode is rated according to the current you wish to pass, or if not, put several diodes in parallel so that the ratings add up.  Also make sure there is adequate heatsinking provided for the diodes.  The amount of heat generated would 0.65*I, where I is the maximum current expected to pass.